# Can I use navigation pages and utilize the whole screen?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to use Navigation to push and pop my content pages, however I have to support some older phones with not great resolution, so I need as much screen as possible. When I navigate to a content page using navigation push, I get extra space and a line at the top (Not what I want):

[image: Extra Space and Line on Top]

However, if I just set Application.Current.MainPage, I get to use the whole screen which is what I would like:

[image: Whole Screen Available]

Is there anyway to use Navigation pages and utilize the whole screen the same as when I set Application.Current.MainPage?

Thanks

Comment: You could [hide](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18074/ios-how-can-i-hide-navigation-bar-while-using-xamarin-forms) `NavigationBar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could hide `NavigationBar` in constructor of your page:

```
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I swear I looked at every setting. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the Navigation Bar if you need access to area at the top. 
You can do it via the [SetHasNavigationBar](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/System.Boolean/) method.

From XAML :

```
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
    ..... >
</ContentPage>
```

From Code (in the constructor or ViewAppearing):

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```